# Python assign time, latitude & longitude to `Dimensions` of xarray.DataSet from netcdf file

Tags: python, dataframe, geocoding, netcdf, python-xarray

### 1. I need to assign `time` as a `Dimension` to the `xarray.DataSet` object

### 2. I need to assign `lat`/`lon` as a `Dimension`

---

I have downloaded vegetation health data from the NOAA FTP service [here](ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/VH/).

The help documentation is [here](https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/emb/vci/VH_doc/VHP_uguide_v2.0_2018_0727.pdf).

There are `2030` weekly files so any help doing this in parallel is very much appreciated.

```
  In [0]: ls | wc -l
  2030
```

### The Problem:

The major issue is that the data has come weekly, without a `time` dimension (except for a day number in the `.nc` `global attributes` and the `year` in the filename).

For the file named `'VHP.G04.C07.NH.P1992014.VH.nc'`:

```
In [1]: xr.open_dataset('VHP.G04.C07.NH.P1992014.VH.nc')
Out[1]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (HEIGHT: 3616, WIDTH: 10000)
Dimensions without coordinates: HEIGHT, WIDTH
Data variables:
    VCI      (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    TCI      (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    VHI      (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    QA       (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
Attributes:
    VERSION:                 VH (vh.exe,version 1.3, March 21 2012)
    SATELLITE:               NH
    INSTRUMENT:              AVHRR
    CITATION_TO_DOCUMENTS:   User Guide of Vegetation Health(VH) system (vers...
    CONTACT:                 NOAA/NESDIS/STAR/EMB
    PRODUCT_NAME:            Vegetation Health
    PROJECTION:              Plate_Carree
    DATE_BEGIN:              92
    DATE_END:                98
    TIME_BEGIN:              00:00 UTC (use day time data only)
    TIME_END:                23:59 UTC (use day time data only)
    ANCILLARY_FILES:         FILE_CONFIGURE:vh.config_NN\nFILE_PRELAUNCH_CALI...
    CONFIGURE_FILE_CONTENT:  [Options for vh.exe]\nDIR_Ancillary=            ...
    YEAR:                    1992
    PERIOD_OF_YEAR:          14
    DAYS_PER_PERIOD:         7
    END_LATITUDE_RANGE:      -55.152
    START_LONGITUDE_RANGE:   -180.0
    START_LATITUDE_RANGE:    75.024
    END_LONGITUDE_RANGE:     180.0
    INPUT_FILES:             2
    INPUT_FILENAMES:         data/AVHRR_VHP/4km/VH/VHP.G04.C07.NH.P1992014.SM...
```

### The Question

Therefore, I was hoping to use `xarray` to:

1. Store `time` as a scalar `dimension`
2. Convert `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` to `latitude` and `longitude` `dimensions`
3. Writing the resultant `xarray.Dataset` to a `.nc` file

   So I want something like this (but with cf-compliance):

   ```
   <xarray.Dataset>
   Dimensions:  (latitude: 3616, longitude: 10000, time)
   Dimensions without coordinates: latitude, longitude, time
   Data variables:
       VCI           (latitude, longitude, time) float32 ...
       TCI           (latitude, longitude, time) float32 ...
       VHI           (latitude, longitude, time) float32 ...
       QA            (latitude, longitude, time) float32 ...
       latitude      (HEIGHT) float32 ...
       longitude     (WIDTH) float32 ...
   ```

### Problem Number 1: Storing `time` as a Scalar Dimension

I want this so that I can later use `cdo mergetime *.nc` to merge all of the files into one `.nc` file

I have worked out how to get the time from the `.nc` file.

```
  year = int(filename[-13:-9]) # 1992
  day_begin = int(ds.attrs['DATE_BEGIN'])
  day_end = int(ds.attrs['DATE_END'])

  dt = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(day_begin - 1)
```

#### 1st Ask:

How do I now assign it to a coordinate? This coordinate will be scalar. It will also need to be cf-compliant (e.g. `Days since 1970-01-01`)

### Problem Number 2: Converting `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` to `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions

I also want to convert the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` dimensions. This is made easier by the fact that the files for 2018, (e.g. `'VHP.G04.C07.npp.P2018030.VH.nc'`) have the latitude/longitude fields.

#### `VHP.G04.C07.npp.P2018030.VH.nc`:

```
In [2]: xr.open_dataset('VHP.G04.C07.npp.P2018030.VH.nc')
Out[2]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (HEIGHT: 3616, WIDTH: 10000)
Dimensions without coordinates: HEIGHT, WIDTH
Data variables:
    VCI           (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    TCI           (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    VHI           (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    QA            (HEIGHT, WIDTH) float32 ...
    latitude      (HEIGHT) float32 ...
    longitude     (WIDTH) float32 ...
    PLATE_CARREE  int32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:               CF-1.5
    Metadata_Conventions:      CF-1.5, Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0
    standard_name_vocabulary:  CF Standard Name Table (version 17, 24 March 2...
    project:                   S-NPP Data Exploitation
    institution:               DOC/NOAA/NESDIS/NDE > S-NPP Data Exploitation,...
    naming_authority:          gov.noaa.nesdis.nde
    instrument_name:           VIIRS
    summary:                   Vegetation Health Product
    history:                   Version 1
    processing_level:          NOAA Level 3
    source:                    VIIRS-I1-SDR, VIIRS-I2-SDR, VIIRS-I5-SDR, ICCMO
    references:                User Guide of Vegetation Health (VH version 1....
    cdm_data_type:             grid
    geospatial_lat_units:      degrees_north
    geospatial_lon_units:      degrees_east
    creator_name:              DOC/NOAA/NESDIS/STAR > VHP Team, Center for Sa...
    creator_email:             Felix.kogan@noaa.gov
    creator_url:               http://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/emb/vci/VH/
    publisher_name:            DOC/NOAA/NESDIS/NDE > S-NPP Data Exploitation,...
    publisher_email:           espcoperations@noaa.gov
    publisher_url:             http://projects.osd.noaa.gov/NDE
    PRODUCT_NAME:              VH_2018_Week_30
    PROJECTION:                Plate Carree
    time_coverage_start:       201807230000000
    time_coverage_end:         201807292359599
    ANCILLARY_FILES:           File_Configure=control/VHconfig.viirs_weekly_4...
    INPUT_FILENAMES:           data/VIIRS/4km/VH/VGVI_21Bands.G04.C07.npp.P20...
    version:                   v2r01,Sep 8 2017
    satellite_name:            npp
    title:                     VH_2018_Week_30
    YEAR:                      2018
    PERIOD_OF_YEAR:            30
    DAYS_PER_PERIOD:           7
    INPUT_FILES:               2
    geospatial_lat_min:        -55.151993
    geospatial_lon_min:        -180.0
    geospatial_lat_max:        75.024
    geospatial_lon_max:        180.0
    CONFIGURE_FILE_CONTENT:    #Options for VIIRS-VH weekly job processing (p...
```

#### 2nd Ask:

How do I go about extracting these latitude-longitude `Data variables`, storing them as `Coordinates` and then using the coordinates from this file as the `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates for my earlier files (such as `'VHP.G04.C07.NH.P1992014.VH.nc'` above.)

### 3. Writing to .nc file

I then want to write it to a `.nc` file using:

```
ds.to_netcdf('path/to/output')
```

I am very much struggling with part 1 and 2 and any help with processing this data and using lat/lon `variables` from other `xarray.Dataset`s would be greatly appreciated.

I would also be interested if you feel that I have chosen the wrong tools!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/292530/115

Comment: @PolyGeo apologies is that not allowed?

Comment: No - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/215590 - the idea is that before you post the same question on a second site, you delete it from the first.

Comment: Sorry! Thank you for letting me know